# How to place a logo in an image using MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing

Can someone help me in placing a logo (for example, the MATLAB logo) on an image?

First I read an image in using the `imread` command, and then on the top left corner, I need to add the MATLAB logo on that image.  How would I do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a reproducible example for you.  @liangbright is on the right track, but I want to produce an example that works.  Let's say I want to embed the MATLAB logo in the top left corner of a snapshot showing [fictional federal agent, turned rogue: Jack Bauer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jack_Bauer).  Here's an example MATLAB logo from the Wikimedia Commons media archive:

[image]

<sup>Source: [Wikimedia Commons](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Matlab_Logo.png)</sup>

Here's the picture of Jack Bauer I'm going to embed the MATLAB logo in:

[image]

<sup>Source: [The Mirror](http://www.mirror.co.uk/news/uk-news/commonwealth-games-cyclist-jack-bauer-3969186#.U-brC_ldX08)</sup>

The MATLAB logo is quite large, so we're going to resize it so that it's a small icon.  Let's resize this down to 10% of the original size.  Once we do this, we simply have to replace those pixels that are in the top left corner with the MATLAB logo.  Keep in mind that this MATLAB logo is in PNG format, which means that it will have a transparency / alpha channel.  This is great because we will need the alpha channel so that we can place the MATLAB logo while making it look natural.  That's the whole point of transparency.  You can use [`imread`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imread.html) as you have said, but we need to specify additional output parameters in order to grab the alpha channel.  Specifically, we need the third parameter.  The second parameter is the colour map, but let's ignore that as we don't need it for what you want to do.  Now, the alpha channel is only a single 2D matrix, while the MATLAB logo and Jack Bauer are **colour** images.  As such, we want to mix **all of the colours** together, and so we need to make the alpha channel a 3D matrix.  This can be done by simply replicating the alpha map 3 times, and stacking it into a 3D matrix.  We can do this by using [`repmat`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repmat.html).

Once we have this, we can finally mix in the logo with the image.  @liangbright has the equation right.  If you want to mix two images together, given an alpha channel, you do it this way:

```
out = alpha*im1 + (1-alpha)*im2;
```

`im1` is the image you want to mix in, while `im2` is the image where `im1` will be placed on top of this image.  In our case, `im1` is our MATLAB logo, while `im2` is Jack Bauer.  Before we can even do this, the alpha channel returned from `imread` actually (it's usually...) an unsigned 8-bit integer type image which has its alpha values span from `[0-255]`.  As such, we need to transform the alpha map so that it spans between `[0-1]`.  You can use [`im2double`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/im2double.html) to do this for us.

Finally, we can use [`imresize`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imresize.html) to scale the image down so that it is 10% original size.  We will also need to know the dimensions of this resized image so that we can properly put this into our bigger image.

One final note: We need to temporally convert the type of each image to `double` as the alpha maps are now `double`.  We need to make sure that when you are multiplying two matrices together, they must be the same type.  Once we finish mixing the stuff together, we then cast this part of the image back to `uint8`, as that is what the original type of bigger image was.

Without further ado, here's the code you should use.  Note that I have saved the images to my computer before running this:

```
%// Load in MATLAB logo
[logo, map, alpha] = imread('Matlab_Logo.png');

%// Load in Jack Bauer
jack = imread('Kiefer-Sutherland-in-24.jpg');

%// Resize the MATLAB logo
logoResize = imresize(logo, 0.1, 'bilinear');
%// Make sure you do the same for the alpha map
alphaResize = imresize(alpha, 0.1, 'bilinear');
%// Duplicate the alpha map to make this three channels - This is a colour image
alphaResize = repmat(alphaResize, [1 1 3]);
%// Make double to ensure mixing
alphaResize = im2double(alphaResize);

%// Get the size of the resized logo - we need this
%// to properly mix the stuff in
rows = size(logoResize, 1);
cols = size(logoResize, 2);

%// Mix in the logo with the image
jack(1:rows,1:cols,:) = uint8(alphaResize.*double(logoResize) + ...
                       (1-alphaResize).*double(jack(1:rows,1:cols,:)));

figure; 
imshow(jack);
```

---

This is the image I get:

[image]

Now, supposing you want to change the location of the logo so that it appears in either the top right, bottom left, or bottom right.  As such, you simply need to change the last statement of the code before you show the final image.  The last statement basically controls **where** you want the logo to go in the bigger image.

Specifically, you have to change the indexes of where we want to assign to the output.  As such, let's do the other three cases where I'll show you each statement, and then the resulting image after.

## Top Right

```
jack(1:rows,end-cols+1:end,:) = uint8(alphaResize.*double(logoResize) + ...
(1-alphaResize).*double(jack(1:rows,end-cols+1:end,:)));
```

[image]

## Bottom Left

```
jack(end-rows+1:end,1:cols,:) = uint8(alphaResize.*double(logoResize) + ...
(1-alphaResize).*double(jack(end-rows+1:end,1:cols,:)));
```

[image]

## Bottom Right

```
jack(end-rows+1:end,end-cols+1:end,:) = uint8(alphaResize.*double(logoResize) + ...
(1-alphaResize).*double(jack(end-rows+1:end,end-cols+1:end,:)));
```

[image]

---

## Minor Note

The images that you may want to mix into your bigger image may not have an alpha channel.  Examples of this are JPEG images.  If you don't have access to the alpha channel, then you can do what @liangbright suggests and simply specify a constant for the alpha channel.  As such, simply do the following.  Most of the code that I showed above would disappear as there is no alpha channel.  The code would thus simplify to:

```
%// Load in MATLAB logo without alpha channel
logo = imread('Matlab_Logo.png');

%// Load in Jack Bauer
jack = imread('Kiefer-Sutherland-in-24.jpg');

%// Resize the MATLAB logo
logoResize = imresize(logo, 0.1, 'bilinear');

%// Get the size of the resized logo - we need this
%// to properly mix the stuff in
rows = size(logoResize, 1);
cols = size(logoResize, 2);

%// Specify alpha here
alpha = 0.9;

%// Mix in the logo with the image
jack(1:rows,1:cols,:) = uint8(alpha.*double(logoResize) + ...
                   (1-alpha).*double(jack(1:rows,1:cols,:)));

figure; 
imshow(jack);
```

... and this is the image I get:

[image]

Take note that putting in the MATLAB logo like this doesn't make the logo look like it's naturally there.  This is because we assumed that all of the alpha values for the logo are the same, where the alphas should be zero **except** along the edges of the logo.  Also, the actual logo pixels (not along the edges or the background) should have an alpha value of 1, as you want this to appear on top of the bigger image.  With all of this, this roughly defines how the alpha channel should behave and thus make the transition between the logo and the bigger image more natural.

I've also decided not to show you what the logo looks like in the other corner positions with the simplified alpha, as the code is basically the same as the top left case.  Just specify `alpha` to be a constant, then modify the last statement of your code before you show the image to be whichever case you want (top right, bottom left, bottom right).

---

Hope this helps!

Comment: another question related to this post :)
if I've to change the position of the logo from top left to top right or bottom left or bottom right, what would be the appropriate changes for it? i mean which parameters need changes for changing the position of the logo?

Comment: @user3801619 I'll update my post soon with the appropriate images

Comment: Good Detailed explanation!!

Answer (score 2):

`I` : the image

`M` : the logo

```
I(a:b, c:d) = (1-Alpha)*I(a:b, c:d)+ Alpha*M
```

(set Alpha = 0.9)

`a:b c:d` is related to the top left corner
then you show the image `I`

you can not just plot two images, one by one, because the second will cover the first

Comment: `a:b, c:d` should correspond to `size(M)`.

Comment: @Yvon I've tried it, but i'm having problem in defining the values of a,b,c,d. i mean for example, what should be the values of a,b,c,d in this code according to the sizes of the images given below. the code i'm trying is this:

clc;
clear all;

I=imread('aaaa.jpg');  % the size of I is 504x672x3
M=imread('awlo.jpg'); % the size of M is 440x440x3


Alpha=0.9;

I(a:b, c:d) = (1-Alpha)*I(a:b, c:d)+ Alpha*M;

imshow(I);

Comment: Your desired logo region starts from top-left corner `(a,c)`, ends at bottom-right `(b,d)`. Your logo image should be resized so its size is perfectly `(d-c+1)` in width and `(b-a+1)` in height.

Comment: @Yvon - I decided to make a reproducible example.  I noticed that with these kinds of posts, actual numbers help.  I think it's a pretty funny example too :) Enjoy!