# Adding a logo to a gray-scale image in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I'm trying to add a logo to a gray-scale image in MATLAB and i've used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25223203/how-to-place-a-logo-in-an-image-using-matlab) as a help. But i'm not getting my expected result. As you can see below, I don't want the white parts of the logo to be visible and only the logo itself matters.
[image: Result of my code]
Here's my code:

```
clear;
clc;

RGBimage = imread('image.jpg');
GrayscaleImage = rgb2gray(RGBimage);

RGBlogo = imread('logo.png');
GrayscaleLogo = rgb2gray(RGBlogo);
GrayscaleLogo = imresize(GrayscaleLogo, 0.2, 'bilinear');

[m,n] = size(GrayscaleLogo);
alpha = 0.8;

ResultImage = GrayscaleImage;
ResultImage(1:m,1:n) = uint8(alpha .* double(GrayscaleLogo) + (1-alpha) .* double(GrayscaleImage(1:m,1:n)));

figure;
imshow(ResultImage);
```

But I don't know how to modify it. Please help me!

Comment: You did not really read the post you linked, did you? You just need to hae alpha values for your logo, thats is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your image doesn't have an alpha channel, so you need to make one!

```
...
[m,n] = size(GrayscaleLogo);

alpha = im2double(GrayscaleLogo)<0.5; % create an alpha channel and show only black pixels.
...
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. I think I didn't understand what an *alpha channel* is at first.